# Filter by a range of values of attribute

Tags: python, django, filter, django-admin, django-jet

I have a model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.FloatField()
```

I need to create a filter on price such that I can input a price range (i.e. min_price=10, max_price=100) and it will give me products with price in that range.

Is there a way to do that in Django-admin (or Jet)?

Comment: Maybe [django-admin-numeric-filter](https://pypi.org/project/django-admin-numeric-filter/) can be of help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ModelAdmin` and override the `get_search_results` method, like this:

```py
# your_app/admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Product

@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'amount', 'price')
    search_fields = ('title', 'price')  # this will create a text input for filtering title and price

    def get_search_results(self, request, queryset, search_term):
        queryset, use_distinct = super().get_search_results(request, queryset, search_term)

        # You need to define a character for splitting your range, in this example I'll use a hyphen (-)
        try:
            # This will get me the range values if there's only 1 hyphen
            min_price, max_price = search_term.split('-')
        except ValueError:
            # Otherwise it will do nothing
            pass
        else:
            # If the try was successful, it will proceed to do the range filtering
            queryset |= self.model.objects.filter(price__gte=min_price, price__lte=max_price)
        return queryset, use_distinct
```

Now, if I input the string `'20-25'` it will search for title or price equals to `'20-25'`, then search for price between the range 20 and 25.
If I input the string `'25'` it will search for price or title equals to `'25'`, and pass our custom filter.

You can find more about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_search_results) it in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    filtered_products = Product.objects.all().filter(price__range=(min_price, max_price))
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be there is no option of such filters in Django admin(I am not sure). If there is an option then you have to customize the code. But you can use in views.py and show your results.

```
products = Products.objects.filter(price__range=[min_price, max_price])
```

Like:

```
products = Products.objects.filter(price__range=[10, 100])
```

Comment: i think its a tuple not list, but anyway that should work, +1

Comment: It will return the list of Products objects.

if we use `values_list` then it will return `tuple`.

Comment: in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#range) its a tuple, but i think it doesn't matter

Comment: In docs it not mentioned that is returns tuple. Filter always return the list of objects.

Comment: when i say tuple i mean you filter using a tuple, i know it returns a list, `Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__range=(start_date, end_date))`